# Equivalent of `$@` for windows shell

Tags: windows-7, command-line, shell, command-line-arguments

I use batch files to create wrappers around some commands which need extra argument to work. For example, I have a file `pip.cmd` which adds a custom proxy argument to all `pip` calls:

```
pip.exe --proxy="myproxy" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5
```

As you can see, I'm using `%1` notation to transfer arguments of `pip.cmd` to `pip.exe`, however, my approach breaks if there's more than 5 arguments. In Linux, I'd simply use `"$@"`, which handles all the arguments at once. Is there a similar notation or a reasonable workaround for a Windows shell?

Comment: You can merge several parameters to one by quoting them like "par1 par2 ... parN"

Comment: @duDE I don't want to merge arguments. I want `pip.cmd arg1 arg2 argN` become `pip.exe --proxy="myproxy" arg1 arg2 argN` for any `N`.

Comment: @duDE YHO is wrong ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Is there a similar notation or a reasonable workaround for a Windows shell?

`%*` is the `cmd` equivalent of `$@` in Unix.

Note:

- A maximum of 255 parameters is allowed.

Example (pip.cmd):

```
pip.exe --proxy="myproxy" %*
```

---

#### Command Line arguments (Parameters)

> `%*` in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. `%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 ...%255`)

Source - [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%*`:

```
@echo off
echo %0
echo %*
```

Running this will give:

```
C:\>test.cmd this is a test 1 2  3  4  5 6 7 8
test.cmd
this is a test 1 2  3  4  5 6 7 8
```

Where `%0` is the command/program name, and `%*` all the parameters.

See [this article](http://elegando.jcg3.org/2012/11/windows-batch-file-list-all-command-line-arguments/).